# Chrome GET request cancels and restarts continously

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, get

I am trying to play an mp4 video on my website using **window.location = path-to-file/file-name.mp4** through Chrome.  Although the video plays, Chrome Developer Tools Network tab shows that that the request continuously gets cancelled and resent:

[image: iamge1].

I have left the Developer Tools window open and it has shown that **more than 5000 requests have been made and over 600 MB transferred** :
[image: image3]

It's beyond me why this is happening.  I have tried looking at the the request and response headers for the first 4 requests to see if I could spot something obvious (I am by no means an expert):
[image: image2]

and the only thing I can see is that the RANGE and CONTENT-RANGE in the request and response headers, respectively, seems to be changing.  I also noticed that the very first response has TRANSFER-ENCODING set to CHUNKED.

I tried researching these terms but was not able to come to any conclusions (except the one that I still have a lot to learn, haha).  If anyone could please provide any help or point me in the right direction I would be most appreciative :)

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT :** I would like to add that I am not explicitly creating a GET request with XMLHttpRequest, just using window.location to play the video in a new window.